# How to get transparent user interface background in Windows 7

Tags: windows, macos

I use Windows 7 Home Premium. Recently, when I came through Photoshop in OSX, I was interested by its user interface. It has got a "100% transparent" user interface background, whereas it's usually gray in Windows.

I googled for some glass solutions, but all of them provide a "transparent window" or a semi-transparent one, which makes the complete window transparent. These solutions do not work for me, as I just need the UI (gray) background transparent but require all the other elements (such as nav-bars, control buttons, etc.) to have no transparency.

Below is a screenshot of what I'm saying:

[image: Screenshot]

Is this a feature of Photoshop only? How can I achieve the same in Windows 7?

Comment: It might be a Mac OS thing; as far as I know, all [MDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface) programs work that way there.

Answer (score 2):

[**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com)'s [***WinSet***](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSet.htm) command can do this. You can choose to make a window completely transparent or semi-transparent (can even specify the degree of transparency). You can also make all pixels of the chosen colour inside the target window (semi-)transparent.

For example, the following command will turn all white pixels in a Win Explorer window 50% transparent:

```
WinSet, TransColor, FFFFFF 128, ahk_class ExploreWClass
```

However, in practice you might find this approach a real pain since clicks on a transparent pixel "fall through" and affect the window beneath. Also, there's no way (AFAIK) with AHK to restrict transparency to a specific region when you use *TransColor*. What this means is, if you use FFFFFF then *all* white pixels anywhere in the window will be affected, not just those in the window's background.

A proper transparency solution has to come from the app's developers; it generally can't be bolted on like this and be expected to work perfectly.